# POST http://localhost:8000/api/posts/action/ 400 (Bad Request) when working with React and Django

Tags: django, reactjs, post

I am trying to build a full-stack app with React and Django.
I am sending an API request from the Django server to React. This is my code how I do it:

posts/component.js:

```
import React, {useEffect, useState}  from 'react'

import {
  apiPostAction,
  apiPostCreate, 
  apiPostList} from './lookup'

export function PostsComponent(props) {
    const textAreaRef = React.createRef()
    const [newPosts, setNewPosts] = useState([])
    
    const handleBackendUpdate = (response, status) =>{
      // backend api response handler
      let tempNewPosts = [...newPosts]
      if (status === 201){
        tempNewPosts.unshift(response)
        setNewPosts(tempNewPosts)
      } else {
        console.log(response)
        alert("An error occured please try again")
      }
    }

    const handleSubmit = (event) => {
      event.preventDefault()
      const newVal = textAreaRef.current.value
      // backend api request
      apiPostCreate(newVal, handleBackendUpdate)
      textAreaRef.current.value = ''
    }
    return <div className={props.className}>
            <div className='col-12 mb-3'>
              <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <textarea ref={textAreaRef} required={true} className='form-control' name='post'>

                </textarea>
                <button type='submit' className='btn btn-primary my-3'>Post</button>
            </form>
            </div>
        <PostsList newPosts={newPosts} />
    </div>
}

export function PostsList(props) {
    const [postsInit, setPostsInit] = useState([])
    const [posts, setPosts] = useState([])
    const [postsDidSet, setPostsDidSet] = useState(false)
    useEffect(()=>{
      const final = [...props.newPosts].concat(postsInit)
      if (final.length !== posts.length) {
        setPosts(final)
      }
    }, [props.newPosts, posts, postsInit])

    useEffect(() => {
      if (postsDidSet === false){
        const handlePostListLookup = (response, status) => {
          if (status === 200){
            setPostsInit(response)
            setPostsDidSet(true)
          } else {
            alert("There was an error")
          }
        }
        apiPostList(handlePostListLookup)
      }
    }, [postsInit, postsDidSet, setPostsDidSet])


    const handleDidRepost = (newPost) => {
      const updatePostsInit = [...postsInit]
      updatePostsInit.unshift(newPost)
      setPostsInit(updatePostsInit)
      const updateFinalPosts = [...posts]
      updateFinalPosts.unshift(posts)
      setPosts(updateFinalPosts)
    }
    return posts.map((item, index)=>{
      return <Post  
        post={item} 
        didRepost={handleDidRepost}
        className='my-5 py-5 border bg-white text-dark' 
        key={`${index}-{item.id}`} />
    })
  }


export function ActionBtn(props) {
    const {post, action, didPerformAction} = props
    const likes = post.likes ? post.likes : 0
    const className = props.className ? props.className : 'btn btn-primary btn-sm'
    const actionDisplay = action.display ? action.display : 'Action'
    
    const handleActionBackendEvent = (response, status) =>{
      console.log(response, status)
      if ((status === 200 || status === 201) && didPerformAction){
        didPerformAction(response, status)
      }
    }
    const handleClick = (event) => {
      event.preventDefault()
      apiPostAction(post.id, action.type, handleActionBackendEvent)
        
    }
    const display = action.type === 'like' ? `${likes} ${actionDisplay}` : actionDisplay
    return <button className={className} onClick={handleClick}>{display}</button>
  }
  
export function ParentPost(props){
  const {post} = props
  return post.parent ? <div className='row'>
  <div className='col-11 mx-auto p-3 border rounded'>
    <p className='mb-0 text-muted small'>Repost</p>
    <Post hideActions className={' '} post={post.parent} />
  </div>
  </div> : null
}
export function Post(props) {
    const {post, didRepost, hideActions} = props
    const [actionPost, setActionPost] = useState(props.post ? props.post : null)
    const className = props.className ? props.className : 'col-10 mx-auto col-md-6'
    
    const handlePerformAction = (newActionPost, status) => {
      if (status === 200){
        setActionPost(newActionPost)
      } else if (status === 201) {
        if (didRepost){
          didRepost(newActionPost)
        }
      }
      
    }
    
    return <div className={className}>
            <div>
              <p>{post.id} - {post.content}</p>
              <ParentPost post={post} />
            </div>
        {(actionPost && hideActions !== true) && <div className='btn btn-group'>
                <ActionBtn post={actionPost} didPerformAction={handlePerformAction} action={{type: "like", display:"Likes"}}/>
                <ActionBtn post={actionPost} didPerformAction={handlePerformAction} action={{type: "unlike", display:"Unlike"}}/>
                <ActionBtn post={actionPost} didPerformAction={handlePerformAction} action={{type: "repost", display:"Repost"}}/>
              </div>
      }
    </div>
  }
```

posts/lookup.js:

```
import {backendLookup} from '../lookup'

export function apiPostCreate(newPost, callback){
    backendLookup("POST", "/posts/create/", callback, {content: newPost})
  }

export function apiPostAction(postId, action, callback){
    const data = {id: postId, action: action}
    backendLookup("POST", "/posts/action/", callback, data)
}
  
export function apiPostList(callback) {
    backendLookup("GET", "/posts/", callback)
}
```

lookup/component.js:

```
function getCookie(name) {
  var cookieValue = null;
  if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== '') {
      var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
      for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
          var cookie = cookies[i].trim();
          // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
          if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) === (name + '=')) {
              cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
              break;
          }
      }
  }
  return cookieValue;
}

export function backendLookup(method, endpoint, callback, data) {
  let jsonData;
  if (data){
    jsonData = JSON.stringify(data)
  }
  const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
  const url = `http://localhost:8000/api${endpoint}`
  xhr.responseType = "json"
  const csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');
  xhr.open(method, url)
  xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")

  if (csrftoken){
    xhr.setRequestHeader("HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH", "XMLHttpRequest")
    xhr.setRequestHeader("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest")
    xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken)
  }

  // xhr.setRequestHeader("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest")
  // xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken)

  xhr.onload = function() {
    callback(xhr.response, xhr.status)
  }
  xhr.onerror = function (e) {
    console.log(e)
    callback({"message": "The request was an error"}, 400)
  }
  xhr.send(jsonData)

}
```

Also, when I run my serverside, it all works well on Django.
When I am on my React localhost and I try to submit some text in the text field after submitting there is no content sent. When I console.log() it shows that after typing some text content = null is sent.
Also, when I lick the "Repost" button. I get this error in the console: `components.js:45 POST http://localhost:8000/api/posts/action/ 400 (Bad Request)`

Any ideas? Why is my POST request wrong?

Comment: Can you simplify your example further or find the part that is not doing what it should?  This helps you debug the problem and also helps us solve it. Start by creating a copy of your code to test. Then start removing anything not relating to your problem until you have a nice compact piece of code showing the problem.

Comment: xhr.send(jsonData) is not sending anything, because jsonData = null